# Problem printing both a Rust reference and the variable it references

Tags: rust

I am no stranger to using references in C++ code, such as aliasing `dog` to `cat` in the following C++ code, in that they essentially become two different names for the same variable:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>  // for puts() and printf()

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int cat = 9;

    puts("Before the change:");
    printf("cat = %d\n", cat);  // prints: cat = 9

    int & dog = cat;
    dog = 123;

    puts("After the change:");
    printf("dog = %d\n", dog);  // prints: dog = 123
    printf("cat = %d\n", cat);  // prints: cat = 123

    return 0;
}
```

([Try it online](https://tio.run/##lY7NCsIwEITveYolorRSrT8nGxX0NdRDSNI0oGlJUy/is8ekUUEPgnva2eGbWdY0E8mYcwOl2bnjAtat5aqeVluElLZwoUonYaFGsgxYRQ2Mg7geTim6IfATbEYtbGBFUH9pOtsmeC/K2giwlQiclqLAKYm@8UyZ4EgN@VHjLESkBCDPo90Wr1D0bhkBr6U/eSMGRTlfLD@Kd6UV5ldvxJ69Xnz1vlP/fzZAPWWE7YyGGUF35x4))

The take-away from the above code is that both `dog` and `cat` are changed to `123` after `dog` is set.

I'm trying to do the same thing with Rust code (to essentially port the above code to Rust), and this is what I came up with:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut cat = 9;

    println!("Before the change:");
    println!("cat = {}", cat); // prints: cat = 9

    let dog = &mut cat; // or: let ref mut dog = cat;
    *dog = 123;

    println!("After the change:");
    println!("*dog = {}", *dog); // prints: *dog = 123
    println!("cat = {}", cat); // prints: cat = 123
}
```

([Try it online](https://tio.run/##lY9LDsIgEIb3nGJkYYoxadSVEBd6k6YObZMWDJ2ump4dC1SNmpjICuZ/zIcbevJeG@iKxmQCRgbzaZGgGwjKguAER8Xi9OYaQ61ZZfyC2joEqhHKujAVSi7Uhydlx4lvQ41QkOdJ7eWjlz2XXW01D9bLzui1TkbJoY4syRLUmNqk925/@KI7a0L3G25JR7pwf8d7df/9p5CZvL8D))

So far, so good.

But what surprises me is that if I swap the order of the last two `println!` statements, the code fails to compile.  ([Try it online.](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09DU6GaSwEIclJLFHJLSxSSE0sUbBUsrbnAogVFmXklOXmKGkpOqWn5RakKyRmJeempVkqa1mjyEH3VtUo6ICM0rRX09SGyxVYwM7ngFqXkpwMF1KD2gdXmF1mBpYpS08DugCgByYJ1aUH4hkbGGC5zTCtJLaLEYUBD0fRAbQNrArFRdSHcwlX7/z8A))  It gives this error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `cat` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
<snip>
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
```

So I typed in `rustc --explain E0502` into a terminal window, and this is what I get:

```
This error indicates that you are trying to borrow a variable as mutable when it
has already been borrowed as immutable.

Example of erroneous code:
<snip>
```

Well, okay, I guess, but I'm confused about why this would be a problem when the `println!` statements are arranged one way, but not when they're arranged another way.

Apparently the order of the final two `println!` statements matter, but I don't see why.  Aren't I still trying to "borrow a variable as mutable when it has already been borrowed as immutable" in both cases?  If so, why do I get a compiler error in the second case, but not in the first?

Essentially, I have three questions:

1. Why does the order of the final two `println!` statements matter?
2. Why should simply printing out a value (using `println!`) create a borrowing error?  Does the print statement really need to borrow or own a value?

(Upon thinking about this, I think that maybe, yes, the print statement really does need to borrow values, just as any function needs to borrow or own any value in order to properly process it, but I'm open to hear what anyone has to say about this.)

3. Is there any way I can create Rust references/aliases as in C++, where one variable has two different names that can be used interchangeably?

Comment: In Rust, *scope* of `dog` should be inside *scope* of `cat`. Reordering `println!` breaks that.

Comment: `let dog = &mut cat;`: that's one of the most confusing notation I've seen.

Comment: @Jarod42 why wouldn't it just expand the scope of `cat` in this case?

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios Rust introduces a bunch of new ideas not found in C++; of course they are confusing to people who only know C++ and not Rust.

Comment: @user253751 Pardon my English, I meant "naming"

Comment: Oh, you mean why is the cat also a dog? Yeah... Maybe it's a [catdog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CatDog).

Comment: This behavior is clearly explained with an example in the [References and Borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html) section of *The Rust Programming Language*.

Answer (score 2):

I think [lexical lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/ownership-and-lifetimes/non-lexical-lifetimes.html#non-lexical-lifetimes) allow Rust to "infer valid scopes" (in the sense of reference lifetimes) in certain cases. In the successful case, Rust can such a "scoping":

```
fn main() {
    let mut cat = 9;
    let dog = &mut cat; // or: let ref mut dog = cat;
    *dog = 123;
    println!("*dog = {}", *dog); // prints: *dog = 123
    println!("cat = {}", cat); // prints: cat = 123
}
```

is treated as

```
fn main() {
    let mut cat = 9;
    {
        let dog = &mut cat; // or: let ref mut dog = cat;
        *dog = 123;
        println!("*dog = {}", *dog); // prints: *dog = 123
    }
    println!("cat = {}", cat); // prints: cat = 123
}
```

As you can see, we have at most one mutable reference alive.

If you swap the `println`s, this is not possible anymore:

```
fn main() {
    let mut cat = 9;              // cat lives --+
    let dog = &mut cat;           //             |    dog lives --+
    *dog = 123;                   //             |                |
    println!("cat = {}", cat);    // until here <+                |
    println!("*dog = {}", *dog);  //                until here  <-+
}
```

As per [docs for Rust 1.8](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.8.0/book/references-and-borrowing.html#thinking-in-scopes), back then Rust actually refused to compile the now successful version.

More information [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.41.0/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html) and, in particular, the [rules of references](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.41.0/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#the-rules-of-references), which - covering your third question - also state that you can have *either* one mutable reference *or* any number of immutable references.

Comment: `cat` is passed as a reference actually; it isn't dropped at the first `println` statement, since `println` is a macro. Actually, even if `println` _did_ take it by value and moved the value, then you'd end up copying the value since `cat` is a `Copy` value.

Comment: That's actually **non**-lexical lifetimes… Plus, when the `println`s are swapped `cat` still lives until the end of the function, the problem is that the OP tried to use it while `dog` was still alive.